# Button to Copy the data from multiple client excels to another master excel , like dynamic consolidation of date from each user

Tags: excel, vb.net, copy-paste, buttonclick

I need to insert a button in each row to copy the specific cell rage on the row and past it on different excel in one drive , Ex, multiple teacher working on  excel and entering the student date and click the button  ( post button ) once they click the date has to be actively updated in student master file in new row, (its like a dynamic consolidation of work )

If Teacher is correcting the row and clicking the post button again it needs to be verify the cell which has unique id for the student and replace the row in master file not to create duplicate row on master file  on each click , i need last updated date and time on the master file in separate cell at the end of the row

Comment: You also need to be more exhaustive and specific in asking your question. Ask yourselves: was i to solve this problem based only on what i have published, would i be able to recreate the problem itself? For example: "a specific range" is not a specific way to identify said range. Nor "the date" is a proper way to identify where and how said date is stored. What's the overall mean of your endevour? Why are you copying what data to what file and how?

Comment: Could you also clarify, are you asking for solutions in vb.Net or a vba module inside Excel?  Some syntax cross over, but very different tools.  Would be incredibly helpful if you could update your question with you best attempt to date with a clear explanation of how it does not meet expectations